# Use of class template requires template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I defined the struct below in C++ to hold a C++ class array:

```
template <int nrow, int ncol>
struct Mat{
    int row_size = nrow;
    int col_size = ncol;
    std::array<std::array<float, ncol>, nrow> mat;
};
```

Then I tried to define a function which prints this 2D array:

```
void show(Mat mat){
    for(size_t row=0; row<mat.row_size; row++){
        for(size_t col=0; col<mat.col_size; col++){
            std::cout<<mat.mat[row][col]<<" ";
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get the error below:

```
Use of class template 'Mat' requires template arguments; argument deduction not allowed in function prototype
```

I am new to C++ and I cannot understand what the error means! I thought perhaps trying this might work:

```
void show(Mat<int, int> mat){
    for(size_t row=0; row<mat.row_size; row++){
        for(size_t col=0; col<mat.col_size; col++){
            std::cout<<mat.mat[row][col]<<" ";
        }
    }
}
```

But then I get another error.

Comment: You may need to make `show()` a template function. These things have a way of spreading.

Comment: Something like `void show(Mat<12, 42> mat)` should work, but then you're going to run into a whole heap of trouble if you don't take @tadman's advice.

Comment: Another idea is to make `show()` a function on `Mat` itself, so you just `mat.show()` or, better, implement `operator<<` for the output stream so you can just `std::cout << mat` and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! I learned more now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your function a template function (the same way you made your template struct) i.e.:

```
template<int nrow, int ncol>
void show(Mat<nrow, ncol> mat){
    for(size_t row=0; row<mat.row_size; row++){
        for(size_t col=0; col<mat.col_size; col++){
            std::cout<<mat.mat[row][col]<<" ";
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can define your Mat struct as such:

```
Mat<10,10> matrix;
//insert elements into matrix;
//...
show(mat);
```

Hope it helps!